# Disable custom php.ini

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess

I want to disable custom php.ini inside my shared hosting. I dont want to allow my clients to use it. I could block the usage of htaccess using allowverride but I cant see someway to block php.ini!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841709/how-to-prevent-override-the-setting-using-htaccess-or-custom-php-ini you have to disable custom php.ini in your main php.ini:

`; To disable this feature set this option to empty value

;user_ini.filename =`

Comment: Than kyou sir! :) But I need to uncomment that line to disable php.ini?

Comment: Yes the 'user_ini.filename = ' line.